# Getting 503 Error when trying to execute .war file in tomcat 6

Tags: java, servlets, war, tomcat6

I'm doing web project using tomcat and eclipse.
i get **test.war** file from my project by eclipse and deploy it on tomcat server webapps directory .

i enter this url in the browser : **localhost:8080/test/servlet**

and returns  **HTTP Status 503 - This application is not currently available**

*servlet* :

```
package com.jwt.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletTest extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");

    }
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jwt.servlet.ServletTest</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: Are you sure that you have deployed/installed war file ? Check for error logs.

Comment: Yes, the file has no problems.

Comment: Please check once if your catalina.out to see of there is any problem during application startup. Also if you are running tomcat via command line see the output lines on the console. If possible try to direct those console output lines to a file to ease troubleshooting.

Comment: @piy26 ,i cant run tomcat via command line , What should I do?